# Why my calendarView is a list?

Tags: android, calendarview

I want to have a CalendarView, and switch month with button or touchEvent. But now my calendar is a list vertical. How can i disable that ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <com.dot.weezyu.custom.BlurredImage
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <CalendarView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:id="@+id/calendarView"/>

        <TextView
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Large"
            android:text="@string/calendar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: [image]

You can see, my calendar is a List Vertical.

Comment: show your screen capture.

Comment: Edited with capture.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want , you can use `calendarView.setDate()` to set date and switch month.